# How to make vim's replacement selection blinking

Tags: vim

In latex files I have the on-fly spelling switched so you can imagine that together with the syntax highlighting there is already a lot of colors in the terminal screen. When in such environment I am running a string replacement, say with `:%s/x/y/gc` I need a lot of time to identify where the string-to-be-replaced is located in all this color mess. Is it possible to make vim's current selection blink?

Comment: `:set cursorline` helps me spot the cursor quickly. Some people also like `'cursorcolumn'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the highlighting of the to-be-replaced text with `highlight IncSearch`.

For example,

```
:highlight IncSearch ctermfg=Red guifg=Red
```

highlights the text with a red background (despite it being `fg` not `bg`).

However, I don't think there's any way to make it blink (and are you sure you really want that?). You might be able to use italics or underlines instead. See `:h highlight` for the options that are available.

Comment: My `setlocal spell` for `*.tex` files makes the typos on red background. You can imagine, in the early stages of editing there is a lot of red and it is really hard to spot where the `s///c` has landed... Yes, blinking would be nice. Or for that matter, any other suggestion that would stick out of red.

Comment: @DarkoVeberic It doesn't have to be red; you can set the foreground and background colours however you like to not clash with the other ones you're using. See `:h gui-colors` for the GUI and `:h cterm-colors` for the terminal.